# Attaching evt listener to dynamically-created class

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, events

I have some code that's dynamically adding one JSON element to each column. When the fourth column is reached, there's a loop and an element is placed into the first column again:

```
first | second | third | fourth |
fifth | sixth  |seventh|
```

And when an element is created a class is dynamically added to each element.

I want to add an event listener where clicking on an element opens up a modal window that also loads some JSON data---i.e. data that shows up in the column shows up in the modal, depending on what element is clicked on.

The problem I'm having is that when my `.click()` is placed inside the loop (to access the class selector) the JSON data is rendered repeatedly (not surprising). Placing the `.click()` outside the loop causes the JSON value of "Category" to be `undefined`.

How can I:

**A.** Keep the `.click` inside the loop while preventing the loop from affecting it and it only.

-- or --

**B.** Have the `.click` outside the loop while making the JSON value recognized.

#### JS snippet:

```
var testjson = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "Title": "Aardvark",
      "Category": "Animals",
      "Description": "My Test description",
      "TopTrainingCourse": false,
      "ID": 1,
      "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Red Panda",
      "Category": "Animals",
      "Description": "Donec id dictum sem",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 10,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Tennis",
      "Category": "Sports",
      "Description": "Mauris sagittis ligula",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 11,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z"
    }]
  }
}

export default class {
    constructor() {
    }

    loadTopCourses() {
        let arrTop = testjson.d.results
            .filter(x => x.TopTrainingCourse === true)
            .filter((el, idx, self) => { // no duplicates
                return (idx === self.map(el => el.Category).indexOf(el.Category))
            })
            .map(x => {
                return {
                    "Category": x.Category,
                    "Title": x.Title
                }
            });

        var curIndex = 0;
        $.each(arrTop, function(idx, val) {
            curIndex += 1;

            $("div.top-training-div > div[col='" + curIndex + "']")
                .append("<div data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal-id\" class=\"categoryName\">" + "<span class='triangle-right'>&blacktriangleright;</span>" + val.Category + "</div>")
                // .click(function() { // -------- this renders modal data but the data's affected by the loop
                //     $(".modal-title").append(val.Category) 
                // })

            if(curIndex == 4) {
                curIndex = 0;
            }

        })

        $(".categoryName").click(function(e) { // -------- does not recognize `Category`
            $(".modal-title").append(e.Category)
            console.log(e.Category)
        })

    } // ------------------ loadTopCourses

}
```

#### Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-id" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">CLOSE</span> <!-- &times; -->
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="category-desc"></div>
          <ul class="training-titles"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- modal fade -->
```

---

#### Update:

Clicking on a Category opens the modal and shows that Category in the modal, but clicking on a second category attaches the second one to the first---here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1lsi.png) that is much more eloquent than I am.

```
        var curIndex = 0;
        $.each(arrTop, function(idx, val) {
            let targetDiv = $("div.top-training-div > div[col='" + curIndex + "']");

            let modalTrigger = $('<div />', {
                'data-toggle': 'modal',
                'data-target': '#modal-id',
                'data-category': val.Category,
                'class': 'categoryName',
                'text': val.Category
            });

            // let triangleRight = $('<span />', {
            //     'class': 'triangle-right',
            //     'text': '&blacktriangleright;'
            // });

            // modalTrigger.append(triangleRight);

            targetDiv.append(modalTrigger);

            curIndex++;

            if(curIndex == 4) {
                curIndex = 0;
            }

        })

        $(document).on('click', '.categoryName', function () {
            $('.modal-title').append($(this).data('category'));
            console.log($(this).data('category'));
        });

    } // ------------------ loadTopCourses

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding the elements to the dom dynamically, remove your .click from the loop and try changing your click event handler to this.  I also cleaned up the way you are appending the .categoryName elements.

```
var curIndex = 0;
$.each(arrTop, function (idx, val) {
    var targetDiv = $("div.top-training-div > div[col='" + curIndex + "']");

    var modalTrigger = $('<div />', {
        'data-toggle': 'modal',
        'data-target': '#modal-id',
        'data-category': val.Category,
        'class': 'categoryName'
    });

    var triangleRight = $('<span />', {
        'class': 'triangle-right',
        'text': '&blacktriangleright;'
    });

    modalTrigger.append(triangleRight);

    targetDiv.append(modalTrigger);

    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == 4) {
        curIndex = 0;
    }

});

$(document).on('click', '.categoryName', function () {
    $('.modal-title').text($(this).data('category'));
    console.log($(this).data('category'));
});
```

Comment: Hi @Nicolay, when you say adding a data attr. do you mean something like: `class=\"categoryName\" data-attribute='data'>" + etc`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it would look something like this: '<div class="categoryName" data-category="' + val.Category + '">'

Comment: The category name is showing up in the modal but clicking on another category attaches the second category to the first one---I'll post an update to my code with a screenshot.

Comment: Change $('.modal-title').append($(this).data('category')); to $('.modal-title').text($(this).data('category'));

Comment: Yep, that did it! You've been incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, no problem, glad I could help!